# SQL returning same result twice when result is diffrent in MVC

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to retrieve data from database to my web page.

I have 3 rows:

```
**ser_num         prod_num  CustomerId   UserName   meter_type  meter_count**
CAVC304222     M451nw     284        abc@m2.com   Colour    5130
CAVC304222     M451nw     284        abc@m2.com   Mono      11311
CNCX515111     HP 4200tn  284        abc@m2.com   Mono      159527
```

In my web page it returns:

```
**ser_num         prod_num  CustomerId   UserName   meter_type  meter_count**
CAVC304222     M451nw     284        abc@m2.com   Colour    5130
CAVC304222     M451nw     284        abc@m2.com   Colour    5130
CNCX515111     HP 4200tn  284        abc@m2.com   Mono      159527
```

As you can see its returning `CAV304222` two times exactly the same, as Colour. But it should be 1 Colour 1 Mono.

I am assuming something is wrong in my controller but am not sure:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = cpctx.vw_ReadingsEntry.Where(w => w.UserName ==   this.User.Identity.Name).ToList();            

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Any ideas why am its not returning the right data from database, as it ignores the meter type Mono, and pulls in another Colour instead...

Thanks.

Comment: What are the rows in `model` in your controller? What code is on your view?

Comment: I know nothing about asp and model-view-controller, but what you need is to somehow tell it to use "SELECT DISTINCT" insted of "SELECT"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just after distinct rows then you need to specify what makes a row distinct. If the ser_num identifies distinct records then you could do the following.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = cpctx.vw_ReadingsEntry
             .Where(w => w.UserName == this.User.Identity.Name)
             .GroupBy(x => x.ser_num) //Replace this with your ser_num property
             .Select(x => x.First())
             .ToList();            

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.